# Failed job in Cloud Dataflow: enable Dataflow API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I'm currently trying to use Dataflow with Pub/Sub but I'm getting this error:

Workflow failed. Causes: (6e74e8516c0638ca): There was a problem refreshing your credentials. Please check:
1. Dataflow API is enabled for your project.
2. There is a robot service account for your project:
service-[project number]@dataflow-service-producer-prod.iam.gserviceaccount.com should have access to your project. If this account does not appear in the permissions tab for yourproject, contact Dataflow support.

I tried to look in the API manager to enable Dataflow API but I can't find Dataflow at all. I'm also not seeing the robot service account.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can see whether the API is enabled by searching for **dataflow** within the API Manager (should enumerate whether its enabled or not):

[image: API Manager search for "dataflow"]

To find the appropriate robot account, search for **dataflow-service-producer-prod.iam.gserviceaccount.com** within the IAM page:

[image: IAM search for "dataflow-service-producer-prod.iam.gserviceaccount.com"]

Finally, the [quick start guide](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-java-maven) may be of use.

Answer (score 1):

You can enable it from the console or just use the `gcloud` command.

Enable Dataflow API: `gcloud services enable dataflow.googleapis.com`

Disable Dataflow API: `gcloud services disable dataflow.googleapis.com`

Answer (score 1):

Adding the **dataflow Worker role** to the default project compute service account solved the problem for me

[image]

Comment: This is unnecessary, since Editor includes Dataflow Worker.  You may have simply had an issue with the Dataflow API taking a few minutes to activate.